# Strict schema validation for Cerberus

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

I'm using Cerberus version 1.1.

The Cerberus `required` validation rule appears to default to `False`, with the result being that an empty document is perfectly valid.

```
>>> schema = {
    'spam': {'type': 'string'}
}

>>> v = Validator()
>>> v.validate({}, schema)
True
```

But I have a very lengthy schema document which needs to be strictly enforced.  Is there a way to default to `'required': True` for the entire schema, such that every defined field is required?

As it stands, I seem to have to paste `'required': True` into every field definition, which seems needlessly redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use simple Python idioms to design your schema:

```
schema = {
    'spam': {'type': 'string'},
    …
}
for field in schema:
    schema[field].update({'required': True})
```